# If $u\equiv 1$ mod $m$ and $n$ any natural number $\neq$ char$(K)$, then $u$ is a $n$-th power in $K$.

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

let $k$ be a complete, non-Archimedean field, $R$ the corresponding valuation ring, $m$ its maximal ideal. If $u\equiv 1$ mod $m$ and $n$ any natural number $\neq$ char$(K)$, then $u$ is a $n$-th power in $K$.

I am stuck at the condition $u\equiv 1$ mod $m$. What does it mean?

Comment: It means that $\mathfrak m\mid(u-1)$, or equivalently that $u-1\in \mathfrak m$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I mean, what does it imply (something about the conclusion)?

Comment: It means that $u^n-1$ has a solution modulo the characteristic of $K$. The second condition allows you to use Hensel's lemma.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Could you post it as an answer?